# At the Point where Force is being applied, why at that point net force should be zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

[image]

[image]

1st image is of question.2nd is of how i solved the question by considering the F.B.D there. I got the answer which was stated in the book. My doubt is that in the 3rd diagram of 2nd image, i had to balance the point where F(force) is being applied as that is a part of massless string but if i balance that point will that point will even be moving up. because i used F=2TCos(theta). Can anyone explain why that point will move up even net force is zero, or does my method is wrong.

Comment: Note that constant velocity implies a zero net force.  In addition, it's not obvious what you are asking.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question. Please don't post images, because they break search functionality and don't work for blind users. Your images are also extremely large, which makes your question very unwieldy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s a very good observation @Kenji.  You are right that if you were modeling the motion of the string, and assumed the net force at that point on the string was zero, then it couldn’t accelerate from rest (just before you start pulling) to moving.

However, in these types of physics problems you’re not really modeling the motion of the string; you’re modeling the motion of the objects attached to the string, and in a sense ignoring the string, such as considering it MASSLESS. In these types of problems the strings only transmit/direct the force. You cannot think of the strings as obeying the laws of physics. For example, since the string is “massless”, any positive force applied to it would give it an INFINITE acceleration.

Comment: To those who aren’t clear what he’s asking for some reason, I’ll try to restate it, although I think he stated it well.

Comment: In his free body diagram, he balanced the forces about the point P.  But in reality, if the forces were exactly balanced at P, then the point P would not accelerate.  Of course, this problem is not reality, it is a model, and in this model we’re ignoring the tiny imbalance in force at the point P, and at all points in the string, by modeling the problem as if the string was MASSLESS.